# anonymous and named functions doubt

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

While debugging I found that this kind of functions:

```
var f = function() {};
```

Appear on the stack trace of firebug or webkits dev console as `anonymous`, and rightfully so.

Also I've seen people defining these as:

```
var someName = function otherName(){};
```

Which are quite weird. Note that here you cant call `otherName()` from anywhere **but** the body of `otherName` itself. From everywhere else you have to use `someName()`.

My questions are:

- Is there any problem in naming a function different from the var where it's stored?
- Does `var a = function a(){}` makes any difference besides just showing the name in the stack trace ?
- Any other tip/suggestion on this topic :)

Comment: Afaik, there are some problems with named function expressions in some IE versions (maybe only 6). It will create **two** instances (for each name one) instead one for both names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem with assigning a function named *f* to a variable named *a*.

A nice reference on functions is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope. Of particular interest is the section entitled "Function constructor vs. function declaration vs. function expression" which has a detailed discussion the on distinction between the function name and the variable the function is assigned to.  (You may have seen this already.)

My guess is the reason that the debugger prints something like

```
var a = function a() {}
```

is that the function's name appears when the function value itself is serialized.  The debugger is giving you all the information it has.

Comment: What I mean by the debugger printing the name is that the name that you put on the right side of `function` appears on the stacktrace. If you put nothing it just shows `anonymous function` which kinda makes sense

Comment: You're exactly right.  If you give the function a name, whether by a function declaration or by assigning a named function expression to a variable, the debugger should show it.  Functions have (1) an optional name, (2) zero or more parameters, and (3) a body.  Since the name is optional, your debugger will show the name if it has one and "anonymous function" otherwise.

Comment: +1 for the link. It has pretty much what I needed thanks @Ray!

Answer (score 1):

> Note that here you cant call otherName() from anywhere but the body of otherName itself.

Not in IE (including IE8).

See http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs for more named function bugs, very nice article.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. With `var a = function b() {}` the named function isn't hoisted and its prototype is not meaningfully modifiable. Take the following code for example:

```
function foo() {
}
foo.prototype.bar = "hi";

var a = new foo();         // this inherits from function foo() above
var b = function foo() {}; // this has nothing to do with the above

console.log(a.bar); // returns "hi" due to inheritance
console.log(b.bar); // returns undefined; its prototype is a new named
                    // function

var c = function() {};
var d = function d() {};

console.log(c.name); // returns ""
console.log(d.name); // returns "d"
```

AFAICT, the main useful method is having the `name` easily accessible (mostly for the `var a = function a(){}` form), which *might* be helpful in some edge cases, I'd think mostly in error handling.

Comment: About the last part of your answer, what do you mean by making the `name` accessible?. How is it not accessible if the function is not named?

Comment: `var a = new foo();` and `var b = function foo() {};` are two different kind of statements. It does not make sense to compare them.

Comment: @Pablo See my edit. I'm saying that the `name` for `var foo = function() {}` is `""` but the `name` for `var bar = function bar() {}` is `"bar"`. I believe you noticed this also. I don't think it's very useful, just saying that if you _did_ want to know the name of the function, this is how you'd get it.

Comment: @Felix Right, maybe I should have been clearer, but that's what I'm trying to point out; nothing you've done to the prototype of a `function foo(){}` has anything to do with `var bar = function foo(){}`. Since inheritance becomes pretty unwieldly here, the main benefit is having a `name`, which in most cases is unnecessary.

Comment: @Bryan: I think better would be `console.log(b.prototype.bar);` in this case. Of course `b.bar` cannot yield the same as `a.bar`. `a` is an object that inherits from the prototype, and `b` is a function. It is better to show that `b` is a different function than `foo` (although they have the same name).